# Is there a limit function in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

Is there a 'limit' function in R? `help(lim)` or `help(limit)` weren't useful.

And in general, is R suitable for mathematical computations?

Comment: I would suggest using a symbolic computation package such as Maple or Mathematica.

Comment: What would be the use of such a function, i.e. do you want to make symbolic calculus in R?

Comment: chl, yes i think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the advice of [this answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20170924085650/http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e11/help/10/07/2296.html) on the r-help mailing list, you can find examples in the sympy help file in the [rSymPy](https://web.archive.org/web/20100827101138/http://code.google.com/p/rsympy/) and in the Ryacas vignette in the [Ryacas package](https://web.archive.org/web/20110522064153/http://code.google.com/p/ryacas/).

In general, all of the work that I do in R requires mathematical computations, and R does an excellent job of facilitating this work.

Answer (score 5):

As @David mentioned, R is not doing symbolic calculations on its own, and such jobs should be done in other programs or with wrapper packages.
Yet, calculating limit numerically is usually quite easy -- in most cases you just need to find argument $n$ large enough so the difference between $f(n+1)-f(n)$ is smaller than the desired accuracy -- this can be done in a simple loop.